# insert data from repeater to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, repeater

my question have a lot of answers already but The problem is there is “sooo” much bad answers out there that i have to be a genius to figure out what answers is going to help me .
lets get to the point.
my problem is simple,i have a `repeater` that include two `textboxes`

```
txtQuestion
txtAnswer
```

i have a bind method with

```
   List<SessionQuestion> questions = new List<SessionQuestion>();
```

that containing my questions to bind them to the `txtQuestion`.

about 17 question (Bazinga!!).
so i want to answer the question in the `txtAnswer` 
and press the button to save it to the database .
i use `multi-tier` architecture so i want the most significant way to save the data from my 17 `textbox` to push it into my table.
my table have this structure .

```
[SessionQuestionId]  [SessionId]  [Question]  [Answer].
```

my code snippet :

```
<table class="table responsive">
                    <tbody>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="questionRepeater" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                   <tr class="">
                            <td>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Queston <asp:Literal id="liteQuestionNum" runat="server" ></asp:Literal> : </label>

                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQ" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>' ReadOnly="true" CssClass="span8">
                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <hr />
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Answer <asp:Literal id="liteAnserNum" runat="server" ></asp:Literal> : </label>
                                    <div class="controls">

                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAns" runat="server" CssClass="span8" TextMode="MultiLine">

                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

my code behind snippet:

```
    private void BindRepeater()
{
    List<SessionQuestion> questions = new List<SessionQuestion>();
    questions.Add(new SessionQuestion { Question = "Question 1 etc.."});
    questions.Add(new SessionQuestion { Question = "Question 2 etc.."});
.
.
.
.
    questionRepeater.DataSource = questions;
    questionRepeater.DataBind();
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this, I've just shown the way of taking the value from the repeater, you can modify it further for your needs.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in questionRepeater.Items)
    {
        TextBox Qbox = item.FindControl("txtQ") as TextBox;
        TextBox Ansbox = item.FindControl("txtAns") as TextBox;
        string Question = Qbox.Text;
        string Answer =  Ansbox.Text;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Answer))
        {
            //Perform your insert operation.
        }
    }
    //Bind Repeater again if required
}
```

Comment: i just used that solution since i asked the question , i searched form another significant answer but this seems to be the best answer tell now, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

No answer is pretty but you can go the ajax route or follow this article detailing responding to a command arguments from your repeater:

http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/04/how-to-bind-edit-update-and-delete-data.html#.Uhlq3VTD-t8

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use jquery+PageMethods.
For example have a class like this

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
string txtQuestion{get;set;}
string txtAnswer{get;set;}
}
```

On your .cs code create a PageMethods like follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveAnswers(QuestionAnswer[] answers)
{
    ....
}
```

Change your .aspx as follows:

```
<table class="table responsive">
                    <tbody>
                        <asp:Repeater ID="questionRepeater" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                   <tr class="">
                            <td>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Queston <asp:Literal id="liteQuestionNum" runat="server" ></asp:Literal> : </label>

                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQ" Text='<%#Eval("Question") %>' ReadOnly="true" CssClass="span8 question">
                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <hr />
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Answer <asp:Literal id="liteAnserNum" runat="server" ></asp:Literal> : </label>
                                    <div class="controls">

                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAns" runat="server" CssClass="span8 answer" TextMode="MultiLine">

                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </tbody>

    .....
don't forget to reference jquery
...
<script>
$('#<%=btnSave.ClientId%>').click(function(){
   var answers = [];
   $('.responsive tbody tr').each(function(){
     answers.push({
        txtQuestion:$('td .question').val(),
        txtAnswer:$('td .answer').val()
     });
   });

   PageMethods.SaveAnswers(answers);
   return false;
});
</script>
```